# Can a dominance solvable game have mixed strategies?

Tags: game-theory

I was told that there is at least one mixed strategy for the following game, which is dominance solvable and has a pure strategy NE in DA

I thought dominated strategies will never be played, so how can this be possible?

[image: Dominance solvable game]

Comment: I don't think this game has any mixed strategy NE in the sense that more than one pure strategies are played with positive probability by one player.

Comment: Thanks Herr, I think you are correct.  I might have misunderstood the wordings of the question.  Thanks for answering this 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a dominance solvable game have a mixed strategy equilibrium?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52092/can-a-dominance-solvable-game-have-a-mixed-strategy-equilibrium)